# Get Cost Information of EC2 instance type - AWS GO SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Is there a way to get [instance type cost information](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) using AWS GO SDK?

so far I have seen [cost and usage endpoint to get an existing instance total incurred cost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/costexplorer/#CostExplorer.GetCostAndUsageWithResources) 
but I just want to know how much an instance type would cost me per hour

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html

Answer (score 3):

From [Using the AWS Price List API - AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html):

> The **Price List Service API** (AKA the Query API) and **AWS Price List API** (AKA the Bulk API) enable you to query for the prices of AWS services using either JSON (with the Price List Service API) or HTML (with the AWS Price List API).

Be warned, however... There are many dimensions to an instance, such as:

- Instance Type
- Location (region)
- Pricing model (On-Demand, Reserved Instance and Duration, Savings Plan)
- Operating System
- Tenancy

As an example, here is an AWS CLI command using the **Price List Query API** to retrieve pricing details about a `t3.micro` Linux instance in `us-east-1` with no pre-installed software:

```
aws pricing get-products --region us-east-1 --service-code AmazonEC2 --filters Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=instanceType,Value=t3.micro Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=location,Value="US East (N. Virginia)" Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=usagetype,Value=BoxUsage:t3.micro Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=operatingSystem,Value=Linux Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=preInstalledSw,Value=NA --max-results 30 --output text

{
    "product": {
        "productFamily": "Compute Instance",
        "attributes": {
            "enhancedNetworkingSupported": "No",
            "intelTurboAvailable": "No",
            "memory": "1 GiB",
            "dedicatedEbsThroughput": "Up to 1536 Mbps",
            "vcpu": "2",
            "capacitystatus": "Used",
            "locationType": "AWS Region",
            "storage": "EBS only",
            "instanceFamily": "General purpose",
            "operatingSystem": "Linux",
            "intelAvx2Available": "No",
            "physicalProcessor": "Intel Skylake E5 2686 v5",
            "clockSpeed": "2.5 GHz",
            "ecu": "Variable",
            "networkPerformance": "Low to Moderate",
            "servicename": "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud",
            "instanceType": "t3.micro",
            "tenancy": "Shared",
            "usagetype": "BoxUsage:t3.micro",
            "normalizationSizeFactor": "0.5",
            "intelAvxAvailable": "No",
            "servicecode": "AmazonEC2",
            "licenseModel": "No License required",
            "currentGeneration": "Yes",
            "preInstalledSw": "NA",
            "location": "US East (N. Virginia)",
            "processorArchitecture": "64-bit",
            "operation": "RunInstances"
        },
        "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ"
    },
    "serviceCode": "AmazonEC2",
    "terms": {
        "OnDemand": {
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.JRTCKXETXF": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "$0.0104 per On Demand Linux t3.micro Instance Hour",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0104000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2020-05-01T00:00:00Z",
                "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
                "termAttributes": {}
            }
        },
        "Reserved": {
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.MZU6U2429S": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.MZU6U2429S.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.MZU6U2429S.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "123"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.MZU6U2429S.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "USD 0.0 per Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.MZU6U2429S.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0000000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2018-08-03T20:10:30Z",
                "offerTermCode": "MZU6U2429S",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "3yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "convertible",
                    "PurchaseOption": "All Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.R5XV2EPZQZ": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.R5XV2EPZQZ.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.R5XV2EPZQZ.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "63"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.R5XV2EPZQZ.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.R5XV2EPZQZ.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0024000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2018-08-03T20:10:30Z",
                "offerTermCode": "R5XV2EPZQZ",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "3yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "convertible",
                    "PurchaseOption": "Partial Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.38NPMPTW36": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.38NPMPTW36.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.38NPMPTW36.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "55"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.38NPMPTW36.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.38NPMPTW36.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0021000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                "offerTermCode": "38NPMPTW36",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "3yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "standard",
                    "PurchaseOption": "Partial Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.Z2E3P23VKM": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.Z2E3P23VKM.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.Z2E3P23VKM.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0052000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2018-08-03T20:10:30Z",
                "offerTermCode": "Z2E3P23VKM",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "3yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "convertible",
                    "PurchaseOption": "No Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.VJWZNREJX2": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.VJWZNREJX2.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.VJWZNREJX2.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "61"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.VJWZNREJX2.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "USD 0.0 per Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.VJWZNREJX2.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0000000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2018-08-03T20:10:30Z",
                "offerTermCode": "VJWZNREJX2",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "1yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "convertible",
                    "PurchaseOption": "All Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.NQ3QZPMQV9": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.NQ3QZPMQV9.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.NQ3QZPMQV9.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "103"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.NQ3QZPMQV9.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "USD 0.0 per Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.NQ3QZPMQV9.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0000000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                "offerTermCode": "NQ3QZPMQV9",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "3yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "standard",
                    "PurchaseOption": "All Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.BPH4J8HBKS": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.BPH4J8HBKS.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.BPH4J8HBKS.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0045000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                "offerTermCode": "BPH4J8HBKS",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "3yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "standard",
                    "PurchaseOption": "No Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.CUZHX8X6JH": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.CUZHX8X6JH.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.CUZHX8X6JH.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0036000000"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.CUZHX8X6JH.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.CUZHX8X6JH.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "31"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2018-08-03T20:10:30Z",
                "offerTermCode": "CUZHX8X6JH",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "1yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "convertible",
                    "PurchaseOption": "Partial Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.7NE97W5U4E": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.7NE97W5U4E.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.7NE97W5U4E.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0075000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2018-08-03T20:10:30Z",
                "offerTermCode": "7NE97W5U4E",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "1yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "convertible",
                    "PurchaseOption": "No Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.6QCMYABX3D": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.6QCMYABX3D.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "USD 0.0 per Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.6QCMYABX3D.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0000000000"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.6QCMYABX3D.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.6QCMYABX3D.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "53"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                "offerTermCode": "6QCMYABX3D",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "1yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "standard",
                    "PurchaseOption": "All Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.4NA7Y494T4": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.4NA7Y494T4.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.4NA7Y494T4.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0065000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                "offerTermCode": "4NA7Y494T4",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "1yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "standard",
                    "PurchaseOption": "No Upfront"
                }
            },
            "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.HU7G6KETJZ": {
                "priceDimensions": {
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.HU7G6KETJZ.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                        "unit": "Hrs",
                        "endRange": "Inf",
                        "description": "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC), t3.micro reserved instance applied",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.HU7G6KETJZ.6YS6EN2CT7",
                        "beginRange": "0",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "0.0031000000"
                        }
                    },
                    "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.HU7G6KETJZ.2TG2D8R56U": {
                        "unit": "Quantity",
                        "description": "Upfront Fee",
                        "appliesTo": [],
                        "rateCode": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ.HU7G6KETJZ.2TG2D8R56U",
                        "pricePerUnit": {
                            "USD": "27"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sku": "CRAJUW7BTXFMT2UJ",
                "effectiveDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00Z",
                "offerTermCode": "HU7G6KETJZ",
                "termAttributes": {
                    "LeaseContractLength": "1yr",
                    "OfferingClass": "standard",
                    "PurchaseOption": "Partial Upfront"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "version": "20200519173025",
    "publicationDate": "2020-05-19T17:30:25Z"
}
```

Comment: I am looking for the info, how to get the price list for EC2 instances and other resources using GO SDK. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @pavankumar [pricing - Amazon Web Services - Go SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/pricing/)